# Как отсортировать список по абсолютному значению?

Tags: python

необходимо отсортировать, но отсортировать на основе абсолютных значений в возрастающем порядке. Для примера, последовательность (-20, -5, 10, 15) будет отсортирована следующим образом (-5, 10, 15, -20). Ваша функция должна возвращать список (list) или кортеж (tuple).

Что не пробую постоянно No output.

```
def checkio(values: list) -> list:
    n = [int(x) for x in values]
    return abs(n).sort()

    print(checkio([-20, -5, 10, 15])) #== [-5, 10, 15, -20]
    print(checkio([1, 2, 3, 0])) #== [0, 1, 2, 3]
    print(checkio([-1, -2, -3, 0])) #== [0, -1, -2, -3]
```

Comment: .sort() ничего не возвращает. Он сортирует список на месте.

Comment: через sorted() так же no output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) отлично вводит в тему. Потратьте пять минут, они окупятся сторицей.

[sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) возвращает упорядоченную копию списка. `key=abs` задаёт порядок по абсолютной величине:

```
def checkio(values: list) -> list:
    return sorted(values, key=abs)

print(checkio([-20, -5, 10, 15])) #== [-5, 10, 15, -20]
print(checkio([1, 2, 3, 0])) #== [0, 1, 2, 3]
print(checkio([-1, -2, -3, 0])) #== [0, -1, -2, -3]
```

Comment: Теперь понятно спасибо

Comment: О, без лямбды красиво получилось)

Comment: вот в след. задаче нашел одно из решений в интернете по друг задаче (вернуть частое значение): **return max(set(data), key=data.count)**, я так понимаю key= это часть функции из словарей пришла? в решении выше задаем параметр, а решении из моего комментария что получается?

Comment: Я не понял ваш вопрос в комментарии. В процессе поиска максимума будет вычисляться выражение `data.count(x)`, где `x` - элемент `set(data)`. Этот код рабочий, но очень медленный. Есть более правильные (канонические) решения задачи поиска наиболее частого элемента.

Answer (score 0):

```
a.sorted(key = lambda x: abs(x))
```

Comment: все равно No output...